# Insert Column In PRAAT

Tags: praat

In Praat, I need to write a script where I can create a table with multiple column. And then also insert data into those column.

Please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Table` objects with column names with the appropriately named `Create Table with column names...` command. You give it the name of the object, the number of rows, and a string with the name of the columns, separated by spaces.

To insert values into the table you need to have it selected, and then use the `Set numeric value...` or the `Set string value...`, depending on the type of data you want to insert.

```
columns$ = "index text number"
rows = 10
table = Create Table with column names: "table", rows, columns$
for i to rows
  # The table is already selected, but it's always a good idea
  # to confirm the selection at the beginning of a for loop
  selectObject: table
  Set numeric value: i, "index",  i
  Set numeric value: i, "number", randomGauss(0, 0.1)
  Set string value:  i, "text",   "this is row " + string$(i)
endfor
```

Comment: It looks like you are the only person who knows `praat`. Can you [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61019222/how-to-apply-praat-script-to-an-audio-file) me how to run `praat` scripts?

Comment: @Joys There ya go